# vb.net best way for not block software while is analysing something

Tags: vb.net, freeze

i'm writing for ask this community the best way for able my software not block during long operation over file multiselection.

My software analyse 1 to n PDF and for every file read all pages. for every page read all lines and for all line analyse data following string algorithm.
In case user load many PDF file the process could be long and could freeze application.

I ask to you the best way for deny freeze in my application.

On this site i read about ASYNC method or Thread sleep function and much other, but i don't understand which is best to use.

Initially i simply thought about a wait timer between file analyse, but this extend time of operation and maybe not deny freeze, which depend on CPU load and file complexity.

***** UPDATE CODE *****
Here a little schema code of my test using Async method...

```
Private Async Sub cmdParsePDF_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmdParsePDF.Click
    Await Task.Run(Sub()
                       ParsePDF(textboxType.text)
                   End Sub)
End Sub

Public sub ParsePDF(byval intType as integer)
    If textboxSource.text <>"" then
      io.file.copy(textboxSource.text,textboxDestination.text,1)
      '.... others operations....
    End If
End Sub
```

...when code encounter textboxType.text or textboxSource.text and textboxDestination.text go on error because it say this object is from another thread...

How could i solve this problem ? My sub ParsePDF() have many reference to object in the form for extraction of values and count a big number of lines code... is there a way for bypass this issue ?

Comment: A `BackgroundWorker` control, or `async/await` with a `Task` would be easiest to implement for a beginner.

Comment: `Thread.Sleep` will *not* work.  Your goal is for your UI thread to be awake and responsive.

Comment: Take a look at this example, pretty good start point for using BackGroundWorkers

Comment: async/await helps with responsiveness when you are waiting on some *other* system to respond. For a CPU-bound task, look into running that task on a separate thread.

Comment: Thread.Sleep pauses the current thread, so the process will take longer while still blocking the UI

Comment: Thanks to all... i tried async method but it say i call some object from another task and it go on error.... in my sub i use somes textbox value for derive somes value.... and from the sub i call database write operation passing datasource object ... Background worker i don't say how to use....

Comment: If you want help with your error, then post your CODED ATTEMPT above by EDITING the question. We can't help you fix what we can't SEE....

Comment: Ok. i'll post somes lines of code as soon... what i mean for now is using ASYNC method, when debug arrive to che real procedure who make the work, it say i cannot use object called (for example refer to textbox1.text) in this procedure because they are not created from the same thread.... and it go on error.... maybe i have to rewrite all code in core procedure but is not the best obviously....

Comment: I posted a little schema code (not real code because now i am not near my PC... Calling the Async method it start correctly, but when i try to use some object (as textboxSource.text or textboxDestination.text) in the core of operation sub, it go on error saying the thread is different....

Comment: The "correct" way is to collect all the information from the user interface while on the UI thread and then PASS that to the other thread using variables so that you don't need access to the UI thread anymore. It is possible to get around this using `Invoke()`, however.

Comment: i don't know how to use Invoke methos... i'm trying to use Async/Await system but not work....also trying with a backgroundworker i have the same problem... it say is not possible to process information owned by another thread...but this object was created for this reason...or not ? I also tried to include all long process from my original sub routine to DoWork event but it say the same message... i don't understand why is not possible to access to some object forms...

Answer (score 1):

you can use threads :
simple example to execute sub in separate thread :

```
Imports System.Threading
{......}
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) 
 Dim BackProcess = New Thread(Sub() Me.analysePdf("d:\pdfFolder", 1)) 
 BackProcess.Priority = ThreadPriority.Normal
 BackProcess.Start()
end Sub

sub analysePdf(pdfPath as string, analyseType as integer)
  'your stuff.............
  '.......................
  'send data to UI with invoke :
  Me.BeginInvoke(Sub() textbox1.Text = "running...")
  'etc...
end sub
```